# Wordpress themes on laravel CMS

Tags: wordpress, laravel, themes, laravel-5.4

I'm working on a CMS with laravel 5.4, and I want to use wordpress themes in it.
I mean when users want to build a new website they can choose wordpress theme on their website. 
Is it possible to use wordpress themes on laravel 5.4 ? and if yes , How?

please help me , thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please take a quick [tour] and see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible. WordPress uses a completely different API for templates and posts and you'd have to rewrite them using the blade template engine + controllers.